# Getting Error 404 from tomcat on intellij

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to run tomcat in intellij, everything runs ok in the IDEA but when I try to open the corresponding page in the browser I get 
**HTTP Status 404 – Not Found** with the **Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. I've looked everywhere and did not find an answer, I hope you can help.
My code is as follows:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.asign.controller"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return resolver;
}
}


@Configuration
public class WebInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;//new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
}

@Controller
public class AppController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String helloWorld(Model model) {
    //let’s pass some variables to the view script
    model.addAttribute("wisdom", "Goodbye XML");

    return "hey"; // renders /WEB-INF/views/hey.jsp
}
}
```

I hope this is enough to help me with my problem. Thank you !

**edit:** I do get the following messages in the Localhost log:

```
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

For anyone facing the same problem: I could not make this project work, but I used the one from 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/
and it worked just fine in my Intellij (after I removed the plugins from pom.xml)

Comment: check if you have any proxies enabled in browser

Comment: Hey, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your `InternalResourceViewResolver`'s prefix to your views folder:

```
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
```

And you need to have `hey.jsp` in that *views* folder.

Comment: It still does not work. Also I tried accessing localhost:8081/, localhost:8081/{My project name} and it still does not work. If I click the "Deploy all" button I do get the tomcat welcome page, but I still do not get my page.